# dynamic columns in Query Or view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

[image]

Please Help me. How can i show dynamic columns in Query. I want a view.
Thanks in advance

---

[image]
My Out is like this.

```
select SectionID,
      Column1, Column2, Column3
from
(
  select S.SectionID,ColumnDataName, ColumnDescription,
    row_number() over(partition by S.SectionID
                      order by SectionTableColumnID) seq
  from dbo.SectionTableColumn vt
  INNER JOIN dbo.Section S ON S.SectionID = vt.SectionID



) d
pivot
(
  max(ColumnDescription)
  for ColumnDataName in ( Column1, Column2, Column3)
) piv;
```

Comment: Are you really using MySQL AND SQL Server AND Postgresq?

Comment: No I am Using only SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Just for tag i was selecting these things.

Comment: I am doing pivot but my out not showing like this

Comment: Then you need to post what you tried. And tag only what is relavent to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible to create a view with a dynamic number of columns. You need to specify all the values of ColumnDataName in order for this to work.

You need to pivot your result, here is an example how you can create your view:

```
CREATE TABLE 
  xxx(SectionID int, ColumnDescription varchar(10), ColumnDataName varchar(10))

INSERT xxx values(2, 'dgj', 'column1')
INSERT xxx values(2, 'ash', 'column2')
INSERT xxx values(8, 'lkhsdh', 'column2')

go

CREATE VIEW v_xxx as
SELECT SectionId, [column1],[column2],[column3] 
FROM xxx
PIVOT
(min(ColumnDescription)  
FOR ColumnDataName
in([column1],[column2],[column3])  
)AS p

go

SELECT * FROM v_xxx
```

Result:

```
SectionId   column1   column2   column3
2           dgj       ash       NULL
8           NULL      lkhsdh    NULL
```